# Game view not reflecting any changes in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my scene view, I have two buttons, and I can see those in my camera preview. But my game view is not reflecting any of those, not even "Clear Flags" change. 
I have tried: selecting main camera and "Align View with Selected" from Gameobject, but to no avail. I have tried changing "Clear Flags" also as suggested in another post, but it didn't change the Game View.

[image: Scene View]

### [image: Game View]

Can someone please suggest what I am missing here. It is a windows machine, and unity version is 5.6.0f3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just guessing but there might be more than 1 camera in your hierarchy. If there are more than 1 camera then try changing **Depth** property of camera in the screenshot. In case it isn't pls share screenshot with canvas inspector. Maybe some setting there is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @jagadheeswar, the problem was due to multiple camera.

Comment: There were multiple cameras in my hierarchy. I followed the steps here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/24917/how-to-choose-camera-for-game-window.html to get the desired game view : You have to uncheck the box next to Camera in the Inspector for each camera you don't want to have as your Game view. The camera that's left checked is the camera that will appear in the Game view.

Comment: I got that problem with a model imported from blender. It had a hidden camera in its prefab hierarchy.